# pydantic with removal of white space

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to remove white space on the first name and last name field, as well as the email field. I am unable to get it to work.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, UUID4, SecretStr, EmailStr, constr

class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr[constr(strip_whitespace=True)]
    password: SecretStr[constr(strip_whitespace=True)]
    first_name: str[constr(strip_whitespace=True)]
    last_name: str[constr(strip_whitespace=True)]
```

Comment: Replacing `str` with the `constr` class as the hint should work for first_name/last_name; I'm not sure if you can wrap EmailStr/SecretStr that way, in either case you could use a validator instead together with `.strip`.

Answer (score 10):

You could add custom [configuration options](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/) in your model or baseclass:

```py
class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: SecretStr
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

    class Config:
        """Extra configuration options"""
        anystr_strip_whitespace = True  # remove trailing whitespace
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `EmailStr` is stripping whitespaces for you, and you could use [`constr()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arguments-to-constr) with `strip_whitespace=True` directly *instead* of `str`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, SecretStr, EmailStr, constr

class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: SecretStr
    first_name: constr(strip_whitespace=True)
    last_name: constr(strip_whitespace=True)

user = UserCreate(
    email="   email.address@example.com   ",
    password="   some password   ",
    first_name="   First   ",
    last_name="   Last   ",
)
print(user)
# email='email.address@example.com' password=SecretStr('**********') first_name='First' last_name='Last'
#
# Leading and trailing whitespaces removed in email, first_name, last_name.

print(f"'{user.password.get_secret_value()}'")
#'   some password   '
#
# However, not in password.
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can use validator with some actions on raw data for field:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, UUID4, SecretStr, EmailStr, constr, validator

class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: SecretStr
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

@validator("email", "password", "first_name", "last_name", pre=True)
def strip_whitespaces(cls, v: str) -> str:
    return v.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pydantic >=2.0, `class Config` has been deprecated in favour of [model_config](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/config/), which has multiple options for usage. For example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(str_strip_whitespace=True)

    email: EmailStr
    password: SecretStr
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
```

PS. I'm not a Pydantic expert but I found this question and got a bunch of Pydantic warnings when I tried to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70262769/722553).

Answer (score 0):

I still use Pydantic 1.x, here's my recipe:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.types import ConstrainedStr


class TrimmedString(ConstrainedStr):
    strip_whitespace = True


class TrimmTrabb(BaseModel):
    name: TrimmedString | None


def test_trim():
    untrimmed_string = " trim me  "
    expected_string = "trim me"

    trimm_trabb = TrimmTrabb.parse_obj(
        {
            "name": untrimmed_string,
        }
    )

    actual_string = trimm_trabb.name
    assert actual_string == expected_string
```